# Politically zealous usage

Tags: word-usage

Is "politically zealous" an appropriate phrase to negatively describe someone who is obsessed by political ideologies, and who is ideologically crazy such as being a Nazi believer?

If not, how to describe such people?

Comment: The example muddies the waters a little, do you want to express negativity solely regarding their obsession or also regarding their motives?

Comment: "Politically zealous" has a mildly negative connotation, to most US English speakers at least -- not nearly as extreme as "crazy Nazi".  As Eva suggests, "Zealot" (oddly) carries a stronger negative connotation.  I would question "scourge", though -- it mostly brings to mind an infestation of rats or cockroaches or some such, not a dangerous political movement.  I can't presently think of any term (other than "Nazi") which does Nazis "justice".

Answer (score 3):

**Is "politically zealous" proper to negatively describe someone ... obsessed by some political ideology ...**

I would feel fairly comfortable saying that the term, “*Politically zealous*,” probably evokes, in the minds of many, certain religious and political fanatics who are currently dominating cable news coverage, world-wide and 24/7. So, **the short answer to your question is, yes**. But that’s a conditional, yes. Conditional, because the definitions of “zealous” and “zeal”---as you can see---carry highly positive, as well as strongly negative, connotations.

> **ZEALOUS** *adjective*: having or showing zeal.
>
> **Synonyms**: fervent, ardent, fervid, fanatical, passionate
>
> see, Google.com [**zealous**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=Zealous+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=zealous+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.2.457879...........0.Y0B69bk55rU&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **ZEAL** *noun*: great energy or enthusiasm in pursuit of a cause or an objective.
>
> **Synonyms**: passion, ardor, love, fervor, fire, avidity, devotion, enthusiasm
>
> see, Google.com [**zeal**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=zeal+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

This last word, however, currently leans predominantly toward the strongly negative, as can be seen by its most common synonyms,

> **ZEALOT** *noun*: a person who is fanatical and uncompromising in pursuit of their religious, political, or other ideals.
>
> **Synonyms**: fanatic, enthusiast, extremist, radical, young Turk, diehard, true believer, activist, militant
>
> see, Google.com [**zealot**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=zealous+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=zealot+definition&gs_l=hp..2.41l912.0.0.3.298836...........0.9GO0dokeJW4&gws_rd=ssl)

Nowadays, if not in the past, to refer to someone as a political or religious "*zealot*" is definitely to cast them in a negative light and can be considered as a *properly negative* description.

Answer (score 2):

I dare say that there are many people who are politically zealous but not in the sense of how Nazis were zealous about their evil politics ( mass killing innocent people just because they were Jewish or Polish or Gypsies or mentally/physically challenged, " useless eaters" as the Nazis called the mentally/physically challenged).

The word to describe such a zealous negatively I think is political [scourge](https://www.google.com/search?q=scourge&oq=scourge&aqs=chrome..69i57.2515j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8);

> *noun*
>
> 1. *(historical)*
>    a  whip used as an instrument of punishment.
>    *synonyms:* whip, horsewhip, lash, strap, birch, switch, bullwhip, rawhide; *historical* cat-o'-nine-tails;
>    *"he was beaten with a scourge"*
> 2. a person or thing that causes great trouble or suffering;
>    *"the scourge of mass unemployment"*
>    *synonyms:*    affliction, bane, curse, plague, menace, evil, misfortune, burden.

See: https://www.google.com/search?q=scourge&oq=scourge&aqs=chrome..69i57.2515j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8